# What are some good learning materials for Affine Algebras

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, algebras

I am looking for resources - courses or books - that graduate students can take to learn Affine Algebras, preferably along with their generalizations and applications to physics.

This post is inspired by the related chapter in book Moonshine beyond the Monster, so I am trying to supplement and make my knowledge rigorous rather than fast forwarding the theory of affine algebras.